# Service Fabric - multiple services with same endpoint

Tags: http, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-webapi, endpoint

Is there a way to make multiple different SF services in same cluster listen to the same endpoint http 80? Services have their WebAPIs with different routes.

```
<Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="80" />
```

I'm getting an error:

> Failed to bind to address http://[::]:80: address already in use.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Placement constraints or use something that allows multiple bindings (httpsys on windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the same IP then you have to use port sharing ie http.sys in windows [More info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services)

If you have different IP addresses then you can assign unique IP address per service. [More info here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/08/09/release-of-sdk-2-7-198-and-runtime-5-7-198-for-windows/)

Otherwise use reverse proxy so all service has the same port, and you specify the path.

Hope it helps

Comment: Very useful! Thanks.